# No EJB receiver available for handling

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, soap, ejb-3.1

I'm working on a simple EJB application I finished the ejb app it's work the entity was created in the database but when I try to connect to my ejb application using a client ejb using RMI I have this error that No EJB receiver available for handling I create an other dynamic web application with a soap web service I see in the console that the web service is generated with an address but I can't get the wsdl

Client RMI code  :

```
public class ClientRemote {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Context ctx=new InitialContext();
            String appName="BanqueEAR";
            String moduleName="BanqueEJB";
            String beanName="BK";
            String remoteInterface=BanqueRemote.class.getName();
            String name="ejb:"+appName+"/"+moduleName+"/"+beanName+"!"+remoteInterface;

            BanqueRemote proxy=(BanqueRemote) ctx.lookup(name);

            proxy.addCompte(new Compte());
            proxy.addCompte(new Compte());
            proxy.addCompte(new Compte());


            Compte cp=proxy.getCompte(1L);
            System.out.println(cp.getSolde());

            proxy.verser(1L, 4000);
            proxy.retirer(1L, 2000);
            proxy.virement(1L,2L ,1000);
            List<Compte> cptes=proxy.listComptes();
            for(Compte c:cptes){
                System.out.println(c.getCode()+":"+c.getSolde());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

My EJB session is

```
@Stateless(name="BK")
public class BanqueEJBImpl implements BanqueLocal,BanqueRemote {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Override
    public Compte addCompte(Compte cp) {
        em.persist(cp);
        return cp;
    }

    @Override
    public Compte getCompte(Long code) {
        Compte cp=em.find(Compte.class, code);
        if(cp==null) throw new RuntimeException("Compte introuvable");
        return cp;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Compte> listComptes() {
        Query req=em.createQuery("select c from Compte c");
        return req.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void verser(Long code, double mt) {
        Compte cp=getCompte(code);
        cp.setSolde(cp.getSolde()+mt);
    }

    @Override
    public void retirer(Long code, double mt) {
        Compte cp=getCompte(code);
        if(cp.getSolde()<mt) throw new RuntimeException("Solde insuffisant");
        cp.setSolde(cp.getSolde()-mt);      
    }

    @Override
    public void virement(Long cp1, Long cp2, double mt) {
        retirer(cp1, mt);
        verser(cp2, mt);
    }

}
```

My Remote interface

```
@Remote
public interface BanqueRemote {
  public Compte addCompte(Compte cp);
  public Compte getCompte(Long code);
  public List<Compte> listComptes();
  public void verser(Long code, double mt);
  public void retirer(Long code, double mt);
  public void virement(Long cp1,Long cp2, double mt);
}
```

when I run the ejb application in the wildfly server Ihave those message that's it's work :

```
java:global/BanqueEAR/BanqueEJB/BK!metier.BanqueLocal
    java:app/BanqueEJB/BK!metier.BanqueLocal
    java:module/BK!metier.BanqueLocal
    java:global/BanqueEAR/BanqueEJB/BK!metier.BanqueRemote
    java:app/BanqueEJB/BK!metier.BanqueRemote
    java:module/BK!metier.BanqueRemote
    java:jboss/exported/BanqueEAR/BanqueEJB/BK!metier.BanqueRemote
```

And the web service soap it's work

```
 address=http://localhost:8095/BanqueWeb/BanqueService
 implementor=service.BanqueService
 serviceName={http://service/}BanqueServiceService
 portName={http://service/}BanqueServicePort
 annotationWsdlLocation=null
 wsdlLocationOverride=null
 mtomEnabled=false
```

But I can't get my wsdl from the link **http://localhost:8095/BanqueWeb/BanqueService?wsdl** 
And I can't connect to my app using client RMI I have this error :

```
**INFO: EJBCLIENT000013: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@10587f1, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool$PooledConnection@176b067,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=pc-ayoub]} on channel Channel ID 982c07dd (outbound) of Remoting connection 01951908 to /127.0.0.1:8080
janv. 17, 2016 6:02:21 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: EJBCLIENT000015: Initial module availability report for Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool$PooledConnection@176b067,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=pc-ayoub] wasn't received during the receiver context association
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:BanqueEAR, moduleName:BanqueEJB, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@80503
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:749)**
```

Can anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: Are you using WildFly for it? I had a similar problem when trying out remote ejb connection which worked in a project with JBoss AS 7 with WildFly 8. Is there a specific reason for using remote ejb invocation? From an architectural point of view, it is very much not recommended - it used to be an idea of the earlier times to let EJBs directly communicate to each other instead, as it's advisable to do, have a layer on top hiding the business logic, such as a REST service.

Comment: Thx it's work now with a REST service